# How to pass request to DTO for assert validation?

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I am trying to implement `symfony validation asset` to the request.

I am passing `form-data` from the postman to the route in controller.

```
#[Route(path: '/test', name: 'test', methods: 'GET')]
    public function login(LoginRequest $loginRequest): Response
```

I have created a `loginRequest` DTO as following:

```
class LoginRequest
{
    public function __construct(
        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank
         */
        public string $username,
        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank
         */
        public string $password
    ) {
    }
}
```

But I am getting following error.

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Dto\LoginRequest": argument "$username" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.
```

Can anybody help me how can I use DTO for validation to params request ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [Serializer component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) in your method and deserialize
your DTO to create an object with your data. Create a request with header `Content-Type: application/json` and send data in json format, not `form-data`

Your DTO should be declared like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class LoginRequest
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public string $username;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
   public string $password; 
   
}
```

Controller method:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;


    #[Route(path: '/test', name: 'test', methods: 'GET')]
    public function login(Request  $request, SerializerInterface  $serializer, ValidatorInterface $validator): Response
    { 
        $dto = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), LoginRequest::class, 'json');
        $errors = $validator->validate($dto);
        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException((string) $errors);
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: You can inject the serializer service instead of creating it

Comment: It's not necessary to change LoginRequest definition. Your method should also work with constructor property promotion as OP defines it.

Answer (score 6):

You can write your own [Argument Resolver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/argument_value_resolver.html) which will inject in controller action any object that implements `DtoResolvedInterface`

```php
// src/ArgumentResolver/DtoValueResolver.php
class DtoValueResolver implements ArgumentValueResolverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly DenormalizerInterface $denormalizer,
        private readonly ValidatorInterface $validator
    ) {
    }

    public function supports(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): bool
    {
        return $argument->getType() && str_starts_with($argument->getType(), DtoResolvedInterface::class);
    }

    public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): iterable
    {
        try {
            $dtoValue = $this->denormalizer->denormalize($request->toArray(), $argument->getType());
        } catch (NotNormalizableValueException $e) {
            // wrong types
            throw new BadRequestHttpException();
        }

        $violations = $this->validator->validate($dtoValue);
        if ($violations->count() > 0) {
            // dto is not valid
            throw new BadRequestHttpException((string) $violations);
        }

        yield $dtoValue;
    }
}
```

Declare any empty interface just to distinguish DTO classes.

```php
interface DtoResolvedInterface
{

}
```

And implement this interface in your LoginRequest

```php
class LoginRequest implements DtoResolvedInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank
         */
        public string $username,
        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank
         */
        public string $password
    ) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer as it may help other people. As of Symfony 6.3, you can use the new query parameters mapper feature.
Check out the feature introduction on the [Symfony blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-3-query-parameters-mapper).

```
#[Route(path: '/test', name: 'test', methods: 'GET')]
public function indexAction(
    #[MapQueryParameter] string $username,
    #[MapQueryParameter] string $password,
)
```

Note that it isn't a good practice to check a login with the GET method.
If you use the POST method, you can use the new data to typed objects feature. This time it allows to use your DTO and handles all the validation stuff automatically. Check out the feature introduction on the [Symfony blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-3-mapping-request-data-to-typed-).

```
#[Route(path: '/test', name: 'test', methods: 'POST')]
public function indexAction(
    #[MapRequestPayload] LoginRequest $loginRequest,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your application tries to create a service with your DTO and autowire it's contructor arguments.

The defaut service container configuration is the following

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # ...
```

To exclude your DTO from your service container you could create it in a folder named `Dto` and add this folder to the exclude line of the configuration file like this.

`exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Tests,Dto,Kernel.php}'`

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but this will not solve the essence of the problem, since the data from the Request will not get into the DTO. At best, the OP will end up with an empty object instance.

Comment: We do not know what his codebase looks like. By the way you're right, the first step is to fix the current issue, the second is to call a mapper to hydrate the DTO on a `controller.arguments` by exemple. But using the serializer like in the above response is more common.